# vee-validate validation message not working in Laravel 5.6.7

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6.7 with vue.js for form validation. I have successfully installed using `npm install vee-validate@next --save`

```
<form role="form">
    <select name="Role_ID" v-validate data-vv-rules="required">
        <option :value="-1" selected>Please select Role</option>
        <option v-for="RoleRecord in RoleRecords" :value="RoleRecord.Role_ID">
              {{RoleRecord.Role}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <p v-if="errors.has('Role_ID')">{{ errors.first('Role_ID') }}</p>

    <!-- UserName -->
    <div>
        <label>UserName</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input name="User Name" v-validate data-vv-rules="required" type="text"
                v-model="createForm.UserName">
            <p v-if="errors.has('User Name')">{{ errors.first('User Name') }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" @click="validateBeforeSubmit()">
        Save Changes
    </button>
</form>

<script>
    export default {        
        methods: {
            validateBeforeSubmit() {
                this.$validator.validateAll();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**My findings**

1. Due to some reasons the option is not being validated.
2. There is UserName field which is working perfectly.

I am expecting that it should show the error message if the option selected value is less then 0

Am I missing anything? Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Where is the error message for you select-field?

Comment: I missed my code in my question. I have updated. But the problem still persist

Answer (score 3):

in the [vee-validate doc](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/validation.html#rule-required),

> The field under validation must have a non-empty value. By default,
>   all validators pass the validation if they have "empty values" unless
>   they are required. Those empty values are: empty strings, undefined,
>   null.

-1 is still considered a valid value for `required` validation. Use specified `empty values` instead. (Namely: empty strings, `undefined`, `null`)

e.g.

```
<option :value="null" selected>Please select Role</option>
```

This should trigger the `required` validation.

Example: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/geaqwr?editors=1011

Comment: @Pankaj No offense. But that is not even a real/valid question anymore. It's right there in the [documentation](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/configuration.html#custom-messages). If you are capable of using this plugin, then I'm sure that you're capable of actually reading the documentation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between your naming:

```
<input name="User Name" v-validate data-vv-rules="required" type="text" v-model="createForm.UserName">
<p v-if="errors.has('User Name')">{{ errors.first('User Name') }}</p>
```

`v-model` uses `UserName` (without spacing). The name-attribute in your input and `errors.has` + `errors.first` are using `User Name` (with spacing). Please make sure you're naming things exactly the same, both in front-end as well as in back-end (and preferably without whitespace).

Comment: There is no problem in spacing or without spacing in username. Problem is only in select. My concern is not username field.